# Resolving Jira Comments in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jira

We are using JIRA 7, and our Jenkins version is 1.647. Our scm is SVN, and we want to resolve labels, and mail it to concerned teams. 
Lets say a developer updated svn cmnt with  EARN-34, our plugins should resolve as jira.xyz.com, and mail it to concerned team.
I have installed JIRA plugin, and configured the url and password. I have used the pattern '(EARN-[0-9]+)' in JIRA lugin, and JIRA ext plugins. The same thing I have configured in jira ext plugins:url ,and pattern. Is there anything else I need to add.

Comment: So you want to integrate JIRA with Jenkins CI? What is _not_ working right now? Why email if you have a ticketing system to store problems with the build? https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JIRA+Plugin

Comment: This is our requirement that the comment entered should be send using email ext plugins. We are able to send email, but as mentioned in the above question, we want that Ticket id should be resolved as link.

Comment: So you only want to expand the `EARN-1234` to `https://yourjira.com/jira/browse/EARN-1234` based on the regex?

Comment: I think you can do that with the groovy scripting templates (inside the email-ext plugin, I assume). I haven't done it, just heard about.

Comment: Yes. Excalty. Could you mention groovy scripting templates?

Comment: See https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin#Email-extplugin-Scriptcontent I don't have further experience with it.